# Tensor product of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I read this definition of a [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Definition) on Wikipedia. I'm quite confused.. so the elements of $F(V\times W)$ are the pairs $(v,w)$, where $v\in V,w\in W$.

Now, if we take $V=\mathbb{R}^m,W=\mathbb{R}^n$, then the dimension of $V\times W$ is $mn$. Then by definition we have $V\otimes W=F(V\times W)/R$, where $R$ is generated by the specified elements.

So how can it be that the dimension of $V\otimes W$ is still $mn$?

What exactly are the elements of $F(V\times W)$ for $V=\mathbb{R}^m,W=\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: No, the elements of $F(V\times W)$ do **not** consist of pairs $(v,w)$ with $v\in V$ and $w\in W$ (at most, they could **be** that, not consist of...) They are **linear combinations** with real coefficients of such pairs.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks, fixed your objection.

Comment: You did not fix the main problem, actually.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think that's okay, since it's my main source of misunderstanding, and the point which the answers below will address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension of $V \times W$ is not $mn$, but $m + n$.

Then, when you take $F(V \times W)$, this space will generally be infinite dimensional, because each elements in $V \times W$ becomes a generator, so you get infinitely many *linearly independent* elements.

Then you mod out by those relations, and this drastically reduces the dimension to $mn$.

A 'generic' element of $F(V \times W)$ looks like this:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i(v_i, w_i),$$

with $v_i \in V$, $w_i \in W$ and $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ (or whatever the field is).

The point is that in $F(V \times W)$, you have no relations. So you cannot in general combine their elements to get to the reduced form $(v, w)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If there are no relations in $F(V\times W)$, what would the expression $(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)-(v_1+v_2,w)$ *mean*? What would it mean to mod out by this expression?

Comment: @Kunal this expression that you wrote, while in $F(V \times W)$, should be read in the same way as $v + w - u$. It is no more, no less special than that. It's just three different vectors that you added/subtracted. Now, modding out means making that expression become **zero**. This adds meaning to it, because that being zero means that now we have the old familiar rule: $(v_1, w) + (v_2, w) = (v_1 + v_2, w)$.

Comment: $(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)-(v_1+v_2,w)$ is just a linear combination of three pairs. One of four of the relations which are "mod out" by $R$.

Answer (score 1):

Elements in $F(V\times W)$ are linear combinations of the type
$$\sum_{ij}a_{ij}(v_i,w_j)$$
where $a_{ij}$ are scalars and $(v_i,w_j)$ are in $V\times W$.

Elements in $V\otimes W$ are cosets $\sum_{ij}a_{ij}(v_i,w_j)+\langle R\rangle$.

In this way an element $(v,w)\in V\times W$ can be used to represent an element $$v\otimes w=(v,w)+\langle R\rangle,$$
in $V\otimes W$.

Note that 
$$a(v\otimes w)=(av)\otimes w=v\otimes(aw),$$ 
since $a(v,w)-(av,w)\in R$ as well $a(v,w)-(v,aw)\in R$.